# close simple side drawer on back press

Tags: android, drawer

I use [simple sidebar drawer](https://github.com/adamrocker/simple-side-drawer/) and i want when user back pressed if drawer open close and when close activity finish. This library have not this function default. I use below code but not work :(

```
final SimpleSideDrawer mSlidingMenu = new SimpleSideDrawer( mactivity );
mSlidingMenu.setLeftBehindContentView(R.layout.sidebar);
mSlidingMenu.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            mSlidingMenu.closeLeftSide();
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*toggleDrawer()* method can be used to toggle between opening and closing of the drawer. So pair it up with *onBackPressed()* method to **close the drawer while pressing back button.**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    mSlidingMenu.toggleDrawer();
}
```

Comment: i use code in function external class . how i can use onbackpressed on function?

Comment: If you have reference to the mSlidingMenu object, then you can override the onBackPressed() method of activity, and call toggleDrawer() from the reference object.

Comment: how i can add reference to mSlidingMenu object? for each function create new mSlidingMenu and mSlidingMenu.toggleDrawer(); not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mSlidingMenu.isClosed())
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    else
    {
        mSlidingMenu.closeLeftSide();
    }
}
```